# Adding dates from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a dataframe which has an addition of dates (which is and index) from an orginial dataframe which looks like this:

```
df_galletas.head(10)



|              | Sales    || Monday   | ....     || Saturday | Januray  || ...      | Promo    |
| --------     | -------- || -------- | -------- || -------- | -------- || -------- | -------- |
| 2021-05-02   | 5        || 0        | ...      || 0        | 0        || ...      | 1        |
| 2021-05-03   | 6        || 1        | ...      || 0        | 0        || ...      | 0        |
```

The dataframe should look like this, with a range of 15 days from the last day of this dataframe.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Mateo, could you please clarify your question? Do I understand correctly that you want to sum up data from the past 15 days in an existing dataframe?

If so, could you please share a short snippet to reproduce the dataframe?